# Is there an RSS feed for academic jobs published on Euraxess?

Tags: job-search, europe

Euraxess is an European platform collecting academic job offers.

There was previously an RSS feed at http://ec.europa.eu/euraxess/rssJV.cfm. However, this URL is dead.

Is there a new RSS feed for academic jobs published on Euraxess?

Answer (score 6):

The new RSS feed URL is https://euraxess.ec.europa.eu/job-feed (given by Support team over email)

Comment: Now down... I've emailed support team but they didn't get what the question meant. Reiterating.