# How to select a subset of Euraxess's RSS Feed?

Tags: job-search, europe, automation

From this [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/103077/130408), I was able to get the RSS feed for Euraxess.

However, is there any way I can select a subset of this? I am interested only in Astronomy jobs, so I would like to know if a filter to just have an RSS feed for Astronomy jobs from Euraxess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Euraxess does not offer this more specific feed, there are two options I'm aware of. You can use an RSS reader with built-in keyword filtering capabilities, or a service such as [siftrss](https://siftrss.com/) to generate a filtered feed. Some more options are mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rss/comments/7yvr49/any_service_that_can_filter_rss_feeds/).

Comment: Most RSS feeds only give the X most recent entries (X can vary). This is by design, to give the newest information and not waste bandwidth. Of course, it doesn't necessarily suit human reading patterns. I think the simplest approach is to just use an RSS reader that stores the feeds. You could try something like https://theoldreader.com/ for example, if your current reader doesn't support it.