# Subscribing to job announcement list

Tags: job-search

I was trying to get the feed from specialised jobs like this one: https://dmatheorynet.blogspot.com/
in my email.

However, there doesn't seem to be a standard method for this. A friend suggested to use an RSS feed application, but I'm not sure how these works. In fact, I had trouble getting jobs from Euraxess before but it seems that an RSS feed application is the right way to do it (see [How to select a subset of Euraxess's RSS Feed?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/181169/how-to-select-a-subset-of-euraxesss-rss-feed) and [Is there an RSS feed for academic jobs published on Euraxess?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/103076/is-there-an-rss-feed-for-academic-jobs-published-on-euraxess)).

Perhaps with this simple site, it's easier to explain how this can be set up?

Comment: @Anyon Im trying to get the posts into my email. But there doesn't seem to be a simple way of doing so.

Comment: I don't think this site is the place to ask when you have technical problems with software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you linked to seems to only post announcements submitted to the two mailing lists linked on the left, and (at least recently) predominantly those submitted to the DMANet list. Clicking those links brings you to instructions to directly sign up for the mailing lists. For that site, this seems like the most straightforward approach.

Now, if you prefer to use the blog's feed, look under "Subscribe To" and pick the "Atom" option. [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(web_standard)) is a feed standard developed as an alternative to RSS, but is functionally very similar and supported by most feed readers that can handle RSS. Now, you probably don't want to read the [raw feed](https://dmatheorynet.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default) directly. The traditional approach is to use a feed reader, whether as software you run yourself that periodically downloads the feed, or as a web service. (Personally, I like [The Old Reader](https://theoldreader.com/).) But there are also services like [Feedrabbit](https://feedrabbit.com/) that will deliver new posts from a feed to you by email. Some alternative services are listed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rss/comments/pvvl3t/service_similar_to_feedrabbitblogtrottr_that/).